# R add in/populate missing combinations dcast reshape2 table

Tags: r, formatting, reshape

This is my data table:

```
Name.1 <- c(rep("IVa",12),rep("VIa",10),rep("VIIb",3),rep("IVa",5))
qrt <- c(rep("Q1",6),rep("Q3",10),rep("Q4",3),rep("Q1",5),rep("Q1",3),rep("Q3",3))
variable <- c(rep("wtTonnes",30))
value <- c(201:230)

df <- data.frame(Name.1,qrt,variable,value)
df1 <- dcast(df, Name.1 ~ qrt, fun.aggregate=sum, value.var="value",margins=TRUE)
```

It gives me an output like this;

```
Name.1  Q1     Q3    Q4    (all)
IVa     1674   1944  0     3618
VIa     663    858   654   2175
VIIb    672    0     0     672
(all)   3009   2802  654   6465
```

The 'qrt' values Q1, Q3, Q4 represent quarters of the year. Basically I would like the table to include missing quarters and populate with 0. As every year when I run the script there could be wtTonne values for any combination of quarters and I don't want to hard code each time to add whichever are missing.

In this case I would like it to look like:

```
Name.1  Q1     Q2    Q3    Q4    (all)
IVa     1674   0     1944  0     3618
VIa     663    0     858   654   2175
VIIb    672    0     0     0     672
(all)   3009   0     2802  654   6465
```

Is it possible to pass a list to a table or the raw data at any stage to say which columns I want to have? (i.e. there always to be Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) with dummy values if needs be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should give you the required output:

```
 df$qrt <- factor(df$qrt, levels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))
 df1 <- dcast(df, Name.1 ~ qrt, fun.aggregate=sum, value.var="value",margins=TRUE, drop = F)
```

At first, I tell `R` that `qrt` is a factor with the corresponding levels, including the level that does not occur, and then I tell `dcast` to avoid droppping unused combinations. This gives:

```
   Name.1   Q1 Q2   Q3  Q4 (all)
 1    IVa 1674  0 1944   0  3618
 2    VIa  663  0  858 654  2175
 3   VIIb  672  0    0   0   672
 4  (all) 3009  0 2802 654  6465
```